# Filter rows flexibly by first and last value of grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with `f`requency counts of words and the number of non-`NA` counts in column `size`:

```
df <- structure(list(size = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4), 
                     f1 = c(100L, 87L, 100L, 100L,100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), 
                     f2 = c(97L, 88L, 96L, 93L, 99L, 100L, 88L, 105L), 
                     f3 = c(99L, 77L, 96L, 66L, 95L, 88L, 87L, 80L), 
                     f4 = c(77L, 67L, 66L, 30L, 27L, 39L, 82L, 80L),
                     f5 = c(NA, 61L, 70L, 29L, 22L, 33L, 44L, NA),
                     f6 = c(NA, NA, 18L, 90L, 9L, 11L, NA, NA),
                     f7 = c(NA, NA, NA, 24L, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is filter the dataframe for **rows** where the `f`values **continuously decrease**. I'm able to do this with `is.unsorted` in `dplyr`like so:

```
df %>%
  select(matches("f\\d")) %>%
  filter(apply(., 1, function(x) !is.unsorted(rev(x), na.rm = T, strictly = FALSE)))
   f1  f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
1 100  99 95 27 22  9 NA
2 100 100 88 39 33 11 NA
3 100  88 87 82 44 NA NA
```

However, this method is too rigid as it requires that the decrease be steady across **all** columns. I'd like to take a more flexible approach by filtering for rows where **only the first two `f` values and the last two *positive* `f` values grouped by `size` must decrease**.

How can this be done?

**EXPECTED**:

```
df 
  size  f1  f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
3    6 100  96 96 66 70 18 NA
4    7 100  93 66 30 29 90 24
5    6 100  99 95 27 22  9 NA
6    6 100 100 88 39 33 11 NA
7    5 100  88 87 82 44 NA NA
```

Comment: Do you mean where first two OR last two are in increasing ordered must be filtered out?

Comment: I mean both first two AND last two must be continuously decreasing (consecutive same values are allowed, e.g. 3,3,2,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another approach** using `purrr` and `tidyr::nest`

- Here `cond` column will give you `TRUE` which fits in your critera and `FALSE` which doesn't.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(F1 = f1,
         F2 = f2,
         Fn_1 = get(paste0('f', size - 1)),
         Fn = get(paste0('f', size))) %>%
  nest(cond = c(F1, F2, Fn_1, Fn)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cond = map(cond, ~ .x %>% 
                      pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
                      mutate(value = c(0, diff(value)) >0) %>%
                      summarise(d = !sum(value)) %>%
                      pull(d)
                    )) %>%
  unnest(cond)

# A tibble: 8 x 9
   size    f1    f2    f3    f4    f5    f6    f7 cond 
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
1     4   100    97    99    77    NA    NA    NA FALSE
2     5    87    88    77    67    61    NA    NA FALSE
3     6   100    96    96    66    70    18    NA TRUE 
4     7   100    93    66    30    29    90    24 TRUE 
5     6   100    99    95    27    22     9    NA TRUE 
6     6   100   100    88    39    33    11    NA TRUE 
7     5   100    88    87    82    44    NA    NA TRUE 
8     4   100   105    80    80    NA    NA    NA FALSE
```

---

**Earlier Answer** I think you may do this with `semi_join` in `tidyverse` (Matches with your expected results)

- First expression inside parenthesis need to be seen

  - `df` has been pivoted
  - for every group (row) only four rows are kept and rest are filtered out
  - Differences checked whether `dummy` col is always negative or `0`
  - If at least one TRUE in any group, that will sum(dummy) in that group `>0` and will therefore be filtered out
  - the `rowids` where your condition is met have been kept.
- Now the above `rowid`s have been used as a filter join (`semi_join`)for original `df` giving us the rows we need.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  semi_join(df %>% 
              mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
              pivot_longer(starts_with('f'), values_drop_na = T) %>%
              group_by(rowid) %>%
              slice(unique(1:2, (n()-1):n())) %>%
              mutate(dummy = c(0, diff(value)) > 0) %>%
              summarise(sum = sum(dummy)) %>%
              filter(sum == 0) %>%
              select(rowid), by = 'rowid') %>%
  select(-rowid)
  size  f1  f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
1    6 100  96 96 66 70 18 NA
2    7 100  93 66 30 29 90 24
3    6 100  99 95 27 22  9 NA
4    6 100 100 88 39 33 11 NA
5    5 100  88 87 82 44 NA NA
```

Comment: I'm wondering how one could work from here: `df %>%
  select(-size) %>%
  mutate(f = apply(., 1, function(x) na.omit(x)))`

Comment: You may use `purrr` family of function on `f` to check your condition, but I feel that'd be a longer method.

Comment: Thanks again for your good work. May I ask you one more question: if I try to adapt your code so that the **first three** and the **last three** values are combined from the `f`columns like so `slice(1:3, (n()-2):n())` I get this error: `Error: slice() expressions should return either all positive or all negative.` (NB: in my actual data the `f` columns go up to `25`.)

Comment: Ok, but what is the minimum `size`?

Comment: It seems that some of the rows are of size, less than 3!  However, let me edit it, so that it'll work in that case too

Comment: I re-checked it.  It is working in those cases too.  However, I have wrapped the expr inside slice with `unique`.  See if that helps

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million. That seems to have worked!

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick. The change did not produce an erro but it seems to produce incorrect results, e.g., I get this sequence returned when looking for  decreasing order of first three and the last three values: `169024
19688
392
21917
497
128004`

Comment: @AnilGoyal it looks really nice and it is always great to explore new ways of dealing with the same problem. The only problem with your new code is the execution time. As soon as I saw the `get`, `paste` combination I was reminded of one of my solutions that turned out to be so slow and I think that's the case here. But it's a nice approach anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `pmap` & `map` approach

```
 pmap(df, ~na.omit(c(...)) %>% .[unique(c(2:3, length(.)-1,length(.)))] %>% diff(.) <= 0) %>% 
 map_lgl(all) %>% 
 df[.,]
  size  f1  f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
3    6 100  96 96 66 70 18 NA
4    7 100  93 66 30 29 90 24
5    6 100  99 95 27 22  9 NA
6    6 100 100 88 39 33 11 NA
7    5 100  88 87 82 44 NA NA
```

Within `pmap` the `NA`s are removed, then the first two and the last two columns are selected and lastly the difference is checked to be less or equal then zero. The map function checks if the condition is `TRUE` across all values. Finally `df` is subsetted.

Only trailing `NA`s can be removed using `zoo::na.trim(c(...), sides = "right")`

Comment: Nice try. Line 1 should be filtered out because the third number is greater than the second number: `100  97 99 77 NA NA NA`. Also, I have varying `size`s between 3 and 25

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann: I still don't get it. You say "[...] only the first two f values and the last two positive f values grouped by size must decrease". Thus, row one seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: @Roman I think the OP would like the second element and also the second to last non_NA element to also be in decreasing order. So row 1 should be filtered out as `99` is greater than `97` but row 2 for example remains as `70` is smaller than `96`.

Comment: I really like your solution as it taught me a valuable lesson. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Dedicated** to my friend @AnilGoyal

You can also use this approach, it may sound a bit complicated but I tried to propose a different & flexible solution. It took me quite a while to understand what is exactly the conditions to be applied but thanks to dear @AnilGoyal I finally found out.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(dec = pmap(df %>% 
                      select(!size), ~ diff(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))][1:2]) <= 0 & 
                      diff(rev(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))][2:1])) <= 0 & 
                      diff(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))][c(2, length(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))]) - 1)]) <= 0)) %>%
  filter(dec == TRUE) %>%
  select(-dec)

  size  f1  f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
1    6 100  96 96 66 70 18 NA
2    7 100  93 66 30 29 90 24
3    6 100  99 95 27 22  9 NA
4    6 100 100 88 39 33 11 NA
5    5 100  88 87 82 44 NA NA
```

First & second logical expression will check if first two values as well as last two non_NA values are in decreasing order at the same time. While the third one will check whether the second element and second to last element are also in decreasing order.

Comment: :) I tried similar approach with nest.  Will upload it to have you a look on it.

Comment: It was a very good learning opportunity as I tried some ideas I never used before.

Comment: I added an alternative approach, using `purrr::map`.  Please have a look in your free time.